# How to parse json response ajax

Tags: javascript, json, web-services, parsing, jquery-select2

i have to use this webservice:

```
https://**urlHidden**/?token=**tokenhidden**&service=1&type=1&from=contacto-registro&q=main avenue
```

I have the following response (kinda proxy of google autocomplete):

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "id": "EilNYWluIFN0cmVldCwgQ29mZmV5dmlsbGUsIEthbnNhcywgRUUuIFVVLiIuKiwKFAoSCVt0INUWgreHEZSY9RjWjyjKEhQKEgl7mbvYYIS3hxFwzLJwOPRvMQ",
            "value": "Main Street, Coffeyville, Kansas, EE. UU."
        },
        {
            "id": "EitNYWluIEF2ZW51ZSwgUGFzc2FpYywgTnVldmEgSmVyc2V5LCBFRS4gVVUuIi4qLAoUChIJ_7Wdp9T-wokRw1OYMU6oYkMSFAoSCZtKxyzU_sKJEYMsBts4ASqB",
            "value": "Main Avenue, Passaic, Nueva Jersey, EE. UU."
        },
        {
            "id": "EidFYXN0IE1haW4gU3RyZWV0LCBUeXJvLCBLYW5zYXMsIEVFLiBVVS4iLiosChQKEgl53l1O13u3hxHCNKLUGbpuIRIUChIJWR7wnNB7t4cRuM2NY71ufM0",
            "value": "East Main Street, Tyro, Kansas, EE. UU."
        },
        {
            "id": "EidXZXN0IE1haW4gU3RyZWV0LCBUeXJvLCBLYW5zYXMsIEVFLiBVVS4iLiosChQKEgkJaDsa0Hu3hxHMoYOfYaBnKxIUChIJWR7wnNB7t4cRuM2NY71ufM0",
            "value": "West Main Street, Tyro, Kansas, EE. UU."
        },
        {
            "id": "EiVNYWluIFN0cmVldCwgTGliZXJ0eSwgS2Fuc2FzLCBFRS4gVVUuIi4qLAoUChIJ_e3Ap4SHt4cRjQnGfC4uqlASFAoSCdudQGKEh7eHEX794InV8vLz",
            "value": "Main Street, Liberty, Kansas, EE. UU."
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
}
```

and i need to put that on this select2 (Id and value)

```
 <select class="select2 select2-form-control" id="direccionContactoAuto" name="direccionContactoAuto" style="width:300px"></select>
```

tried this with no avail:

```
$('#direccionContactoAuto').select2({
        ajax: {
            url: '**URL hidden**',
            type: 'GET',
            data: function (params) {
                var query = {
                    token:'**token hidden**',
                    service: '1',
                    type: '1',
                    q: params.term,
                    from: 'form-cont'
                }
                return query;
            }
        }
    });
```

remarking that i have no clue of what im doing and getting to this point looking for examples.

there is no response, not auto charge of info, i suspect that im lacking some catch to get the select to reload from the sevice when user types.... tried this:

```
 $("#direccionContactoAuto").select2({
                formatNoMatches: function (term) {
                    var length = term.length;

                    if (length === 6) {
                        //***************
                        console.log(length);
                        console.log(term);
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

that returns correctly what im typing as soon as it comes to 6 characters, as supposed.

what i'm missing?

Comment: Documentation: https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax

Comment: Any erros in the console? Does the URL you have work and returns correctly and is not blocked by CORS?

Comment: zero movements. it even doesnt get to call the service once... not blocked tho . there is some other services in the same project called outside.

Comment: is there a way that i can debug whats coming on that query? or if this ajax is being called? novice on javascript

Comment: You can add `console.log(query);` just before `return query;`

Comment: tried some things and this appeared: "Unhandled rejection Error: Option 'ajax' is not allowed for Select2 when attached to a <select> element." 
Retunred everything to previous state, and this keeps appearing on console